# Saving result between script executions

Tags: scripting, directory-structure

I have a script in `/opt` which is called regularly by Cron. The script needs to write and read a status flag between executions. In what directory should I store the flag? I'm thinking that `/tmp` might not be a good choice as the file containing the flag is not guaranteed to be preserved between script executions.

Comment: Why is it not guaranteed to be preserved? `/tmp` should be fine. If anything you can also hide the files with a `.` in front of the name in the `/tmp` directory, something like `/tmp/.myhiddenflag` so that it isn't accidentally cleaned up. I store all my lockfiles in `/tmp` this way.

Comment: Files under `/tmp` can be destroyed on system reboot. If you want to be sure that this flag survive shutdown then your `$HOME` directory is the safest place. I would personally advise to simply create `$HOME/tmp/` and store all temporary files there.

Comment: @jimmij, true, if your system is constantly rebooting and you need to save the last flag state, then jimmij approach is best. In my case I want my lock files cleaned up so its safe to keep them in `/tmp` in case of a reboot. Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Filesystem hierarchy standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) to see what standard locations exist on a Linux system.

If you need to guarantee that the file is preserved between executions, then indeed [`/tmp`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#TMPTEMPORARYFILES) is not the right place. `/tmp` is often wiped on a reboot, and it's common to have a cron job that deleted old unopened files from `/tmp` as well.

[`/var/tmp`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARTMPTEMPORARYFILESPRESERVEDBETWEE) is not normally deleted automatically. It's explicitly not supposed to be wiped on a reboot. This might be an acceptable choice; however do note that the system administrator may decide to wipe that directory manually, so you should use it only if you have confidence that the system administrator will know that your file isn't to be deleted. Furthermore **`/var/tmp` is publicly writable** (like `/tmp`), so take care of permissions. In particular, take care that if your script hasn't run yet, another user could create a file by the expected name, and then your script would operate with bad data.

It would be better to use a location that's private to the user running the script. If the script is executed by a human user's account, store the file somewhere in the user's home directory (conventionally a [dot file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-file)). If the script is executed by a system account, then the file should be stored somewhere under [`/var`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#THEVARHIERARCHY), which is where modifiable files live apart from the ones in `/tmp`. Specifically, create a directory for your script **under [`/var/lib`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VARLIBVARIABLESTATEINFORMATION)**, and give it proper permissions. A variant is to create a directory under [`/var/opt`](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#VAROPTVARIABLEDATAFOROPT) (the convention to use `/var/opt/PACKAGENAME/` rather than `/var/lib/PACKAGENAME/` for variable data belonging to a package whose code and static data are in `/var/opt/PACKAGENAME/` is not universally followed).